# 404 Error when specifying a port

Tags: angular, vb6, ieframe.dll

I have a legacy app written in VB6 and uses the IEFrame.dll that recently broke due to a server change.  I'm trying to debug why it broke, but I can't get it to work on my local machine.  On my local machine the URL is like:

```
http://localhost:4200/landing
```

If I navigate to `http://localhost:4200` the page loads, but if I try and navigate to `http://localhost:4200/landing` I get a 404.  If I try that same URL in FF or Chrome it works as expected.

So is there a way to get the WebBrowser control from IEFrame.dll to work when the port is in the middle of the URL?

This is basically what the VB code looks like:

```
Dim url As String
url = "http://localhost:4200/landing"
wb.Navigate2 url 'This works if there is no port specified
```

"Landing" is an Angular route.  I'm new to Angular and didn't actually write this particular server code so I can't say for sure if there is a redirect or not.

Comment: Is there a redirect happening?

Comment: Do you get same result using `Navigate2` method?

Comment: Thanks @Jeff - it's always good to send a targeted comment when question is updated - I have no way of knowing otherwise. So you're saying landing is javascript - does `"http://localhost:4200"' auto redirect to your landing page - or stay there in main folder?

Comment: @dbmitch, it actually goes to the default route and works as expected.

Comment: This is localhost and you don't have access to the server code?